# jquery.UploadiFive.min.js showing fluctuation in progress bar for multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have imported `jquery.UploadiFive.min.js` file and when I tried to upload multiple files at a time single progress bar showing fluctuation because it is passing event for both downloaded and total for every entry. Please suggest how to remove fluctuation.

Here is the function adding fluctuation to progress bar

```
. onProgress : function(file, e) {
    $("#bar_container").show();
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
       var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    }
    var pos = percent + "%";
    var nooffiles = nofile + 1;
    $(".progresstext").text("Uploading " + nooffiles + " of " + MyFilesTotal);
    $(".progress").animate({ 'width': pos }, 200).text(percent + "%");
}
```

–  Parmanand Punewar 4

Comment: Can you show some code (snippet)? Post what you tried so far?

Comment: here is the function adding fluctuation to progress bar.
onProgress'   : function(file, e) {
       $("#bar_container").show();
       if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
       }
       var pos = percent + "%";
       var nooffiles = nofile + 1;
       $(".progresstext").text("Uploading " + nooffiles + " of " + MyFilesTotal);
       $(".progress").animate({
        'width': pos
       }, 200).text(percent + "%");

           }

Comment: Edited your question, please, next time don't post snippets on comments, try to edit your own question